# driver for MIDI

Tags: drivers

I have a desktop (Intel® Core ™ i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4) with updated UBUNTU 16.04 LTS. I downloaded LMMS and plugged the USB of the M-AUDIO KeyStudio 49 electronic keyboard. The result is that it does not recognize MIDI. Can you advise me what to do? Do I have to download a driver? Thank you!
https://pastebin.com/ba8Z7Pcm (lsusb)